# Create Cron job to execute every wed at 2nd week

Tags: cron

What the correct way to execute cron job to be run  at

Wed in 2nd / week  and wed in 4th week of each month

any tips

Comment: Have a read of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: How do you define the first week of the month? I can see two ways. One is similar to ISO’s definition of the first week of the year: the first week of the month is the first week that contains a wednesday. Another definition is that the first week of the month is the week that contains the first day of the month. With first definition, first week of 2012-12 would start end of november. With second definition it would start on december the 3rd (or 2nd for U.S.A.).

Answer (score 0):

Following would run the job on every wednesdays at 11 AM

```
00 11 * * 3 <your-command>
```

Here the `3` says, the command to run every Wednesday. You would need to create a wrapper script, to just skip the execution on alternate Wednesday, and call that script from above cron.